# Python program to traverse directories and read file information

Tags: python, fileinfo, directory-traversal

I'm just getting started with Python but already have found it much more productive than Bash shell scripting.

I'm trying to write a Python script that will traverse every directory that branches from the directory I launch the script in, and for each file it encounters, load an instance of this class:

```
class FileInfo:

    def __init__(self, filename, filepath):
        self.filename = filename
        self.filepath = filepath
```

The filepath attribute would be the full absolute path from root (/).  Here's the pseudocode mockup for what I'd like the main program to do:

```
from (current directory):

    for each file in this directory, 
    create an instance of FileInfo and load the file name and path

    switch to a nested directory, or if there is none, back out of this directory
```

I've been reading about os.walk() and ok.path.walk(), but I'd like some advice about what the most straightforward way to implement this in Python would be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to assign the created object to? This seems to be  otherwise trivial.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd use `os.walk` doing the following:

```
def getInfos(currentDir):
    infos = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(currentDir): # Walk directory tree
        for f in files:
            infos.append(FileInfo(f,root))
    return infos
```

Comment: Use snake_case instead of CamelCase for Python.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
info = []
for path, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    info.extend(FileInfo(filename, path) for filename in files)
```

or

```
info = [FileInfo(filename, path)
        for path, dirs, files in os.walk(".")
        for filename in files]
```

to get a list of one `FileInfo` instance per file.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```py
import os

for item in os.walk(".", "*"):
    print(item)
```