# scripting language to remove license preamble on files

Tags: python, regex, perl

I want to recursively replace the "blah blah blah"
in my License region with nothing:

```
#region License
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
#endregion
```

should be replaced with

```
#region License
#endregion
```

This should apply to all of of my .cs files in a certain directory (recursive). I tried this with sed, but since I am on windows, I had some problems with line endings. How can I do this with perl (or python), or something native to windows?

EDIT:  here is the solution I came up with, thanks to everyone here!:

```
#/bin/bash
list=`find . -name '*.cs' -o -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp'` 
for i in $list 
do
perl -i~ -ne 'if (/#region License/../#endregion/) {print if /#(?:end)?  region/;next};print' $i 
done
```

Comment: I hope that's your own license and not someone else's...

Comment: I am doing this to avoid massive merge conflicts between two branches, where the license text was changed on all files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'if (/#region/../#endregion/) {print if /#(?:end)?region/;next};print' file
```

...which leave the "#region license" and "#endregion" lines in the output as requested.

Comment: how do I get this to overwrite the old file with the changes?

Comment: @Jacko : To perform an inplace edit, simply change the switches to: perl -i -ne ... If you want to preserve a copy of the original file (with a suffix) do: perl -i.old -ne ...

Comment: THanks.  This script doesn't seem to work if the file is not in the current directory.  (I used find to enumerate all cs files)

Comment: @Jacko : If necessary, specify an absolute path to your file.  What "doesn't work"?  How?

Comment: actually, I needed to replace "#region" with #region License", or all regions would be deleted!!

Comment: what about handling files where there is no #region License, and I want to add this text in ??

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
perl -i~ -pe 'undef $_ if /^#region License$/ .. /^#endregion$/'
```

Comment: Range operator reference for anyone curious : http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators

Comment: thanks. So, if my file is called foo.cs, how would I call this, to overwrite foo.cs ?

Comment: The `-i~` means it overwrites your files, but creates a backup (`foo.cs~` in your case)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('input') as fd:
    text=fd.read()

old="""#region License
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
#endregion

"""

new="""#region License
#endregion

"""

print text.replace(old,new)
```

add some `os.walk` to traverse the directory and either write the result to stdout or replace original file with new content. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5421671/297323

Comment: nice "kiss" solution; and probably adequate so long as the license bodies are all exactly the same text.  If there are a bunch of different license, this could be easily extended to replace each!

Answer (score 1):

`ex` (`vim -e`) maybe is a good choice.

```
echo -e 'g/^#region License$/+1,/^#endregion$/-1d\nx' | ex program.cs
```

---

- `g/.../+1,/.../-1` => find lines between regexs(`+1` => one line bellow, `-1` => one line above)
- `d` => delete
- `\n` => <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `x` =>save and quit

---

In Windows, please use:

```
vim -c "g/^#region License/+1,/^#endregion/-1d" +x program.cs
```

Comment: THanks! this works, but it doesn't scale well to large projects.

Answer (score 0):

read lines of the file, go thru each line if line starts with #region start skipping next lines, if lines ends with #endregion start collecting lines again, output final line into file e.g.

```
def filter_lines(lines):
    newlines = []
    startmarker = '#region'
    endmarker = '#endregion'
    skip = False
    for line in lines:

        if line.startswith(startmarker):
            newlines.append(line)
            skip = True
            continue
        if line.endswith(endmarker):
            skip = False

        if not skip: newlines.append(line)

    return newli
```

nes

Answer (score 0):

python, in case the license bodies are all different in all sorts of unpredictable ways:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('input') as fd:
    text=fd.read()

try:
    start, rest = text.split("#region License\n", 1)
    middle, end = rest.split("#endregion\n", 1)
    print "%s\#region License\n#endregion\n%s" % (start, end)
except ValueError:
    # didn't contain a properly formatted license:
    print text
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
perl -i.orig -0777 -p -e 's/#region License.*?#endregion/#region License\n#endregion/s' test.cc
```

- -0777 means that the whole file will be slurped
- -p is making the -e code to be surrounded by a while (<>) {  ... print $_ } block
- -i.orig does the editing in place, and creates a backup
- s flag at the end of the substitution makes the .* in the regexp match over eol

Use find to determine which files to process